# Pandas filter up to a specific value within a group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm working with this dataframe:

```
Keyword    URL    Type              Position_Group 
A          A      Ad                1      
A          B      Ad                2       
A          C      Organic           1           
A          D      Organic           2          
A          E      Organic           3
A          F      Featured_Snippet  1           
..
A          P      Organic           20
A          Q      Organic           21
A          R      Ad                6
```

I want to be able to filter up to `Type` = `Organic` & `Position_Group` <= `20` while also being inclusive of the other `Type` (`Ad` & `Featured_Snippet`) since its results fall within top 20 organic positions. The goal of this use case is to be able to filter up to top 20 `Organic` positions while also capturing other `Type` in between.

The expected output should be like this:

```
Keyword    URL    Type              Position_Group 
A          A      Ad                1
A          B      Ad                2             
A          C      Organic           1           
A          D      Organic           2          
A          E      Organic           3
A          F      Featured_Snippet  1           
..
A          P      Organic           20
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In other words, do you want to keep rows where `Position_Group <= 20`, regardless of `Type`: `df[df['Position_Group'] <= 20]`? This rule would automatically include "the other Type (Ad & Featured_Snippet) since those [Position_Group] all fall within top 20"

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler sorry didn't clarify this in the original post, but position_group is based on type. For example, if you look at the first dataframe the ad (position_group 6) after organic position_group 20 is excluded in the desired output. Using `df[df['Position_Group'] <= 20]` wouldn't work since we would need take in type into context as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the dataframe is `df`:

```
df.iloc[: list(df[(df["Type"] == "Organic") & (df["Position_Group"] == 20)].index)[0]+1]
```

This filters the dataframe by `Type == "Organic"` and `Position_Group == 20`, then returns the index to a list and takes the first item (there should only be one item, but I have found the list is necessary to get the actual value, not `Int64Index([6], dtype='int64')`).  1 is added to this so that it is included, and the rows up to there are taken from the dataframe.

### **EDIT**

For the addition of for each `x` in `Keyword`, it can be completed with a for loop:

```
for i, j in df.groupby("Keyword"):
    j.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    print(j.iloc[: list(j[(j["Type"] == "Organic") & (j["Position_Group"] == 20)].index)[0]+1])
```

I have used `print` here, but if you wanted to create a new dataframe with only these rows:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)

for i, j in df.groupby("Keyword"):
    j.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    df2 = pd.concat([df2, j.iloc[: list(j[(j["Type"] == "Organic") & (j["Position_Group"] == 20)].index)[0]+1]])
```

Comment: @S Rawson This worked! However, maybe to add an additional layer of complexity here but how would this work if you have to apply this to multiple keywords? Meaning not just keyword A but also keyword B, C, D, etc. Each keyword will need to be evaluated for their top 20 organic positions.

Comment: I have included this in an edit to my answer.